# How to link NODEJS server to another folder created in meteor using Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, meteor

I recently learning a tutorial from get started from meteor, I am using NodeJS Web Application in Visual Studio, then I created a meteor using cmd (meteor create simple-to-do) command inside the package called simple-todos(on the tutorial), what I want is when I hit F5 on Visual Studio 2015, It will launch "simple-to-do" not "Hello World" is their a way to configure the server.js can't seem to find the configuration on meteor.

this is my default server.js

```
 var http = require('http');
 var port = process.env.port || 3000;
 http.createServer(function (req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
     res.end('Hello World\n');
 }).listen(port);
```

Comment: are you wanting to debug a meteor app from visual studio?

Comment: yes exactly is that possible?

Comment: no.... not from visual studio